# Multiple Buttons in One Column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm developing a **windows application** in which I want to add three buttons or links in one column of `dataGridView` Control.

Buttons will be *Edit, Update and Delete* and those three buttons come under one column name `Action`. As per user's selection, *action method* will be invoked and perform the particular function. Is it possible to add three buttons in one column and if yes then how? Also, how will they invoke separate event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to add three buttons in one column

No, it is not possible using the built in control. The preferred method is that you add 3 buttons in 3 columns

> how they will invoke separate event

If you use the method i have mentioned above you can handle the

> For Winforms [CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx) event
>
> For Webforms [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx) event